# how to insert the field values in the connected openedge database when table and column names are given

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

I've retrieved the field names of a table by giving the table name directly (INS_TEST is the name of my table). I used columns _Field-Name, _Data-Type of the _Field system table and retrieved the field names and their data types.

I want to use the retrieved field names and insert field values into those fields.

```
FOR EACH _File WHERE _File-Name = "INS_TEST":

    FOR EACH _Field WHERE _File-Recid = RECID(_File):
        DISPLAY _Field._Field-Name.
        DISPLAY _Field._Data-Type.
        ASSIGN _File._File-Name._Field._Field-Name = 1 WHEN (_Field._Data-Type EQ "INTEGER").
    END.
END.
```

But the ASSIGN statement gives an error. Suggestions please!

Comment: What error do you see? It is always a good practice to portray the error.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  Inserting arbitrary data into arbitrary fields of arbitrary tables seems like an unlikely requirement.

Comment: @Austin - The assign statement is wrong. It.s showing can't understand after _File._File-Name._Field

Comment: @TomBascom I'm trying to create a generic insert. So, I'm trying to retrieve the column names using table name and then assigning values. It would be great if table name isn't hard-coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following procedure takes a table name, a field name and a character value as parameters.  It will update the field in question in the first record of that table with the value provided.

Obviously you could write a more sophisticated WHERE clause and do other things to fancy it up for your specific needs.

```
procedure x:

  define input parameter tbl as character no-undo.
  define input parameter fld as character no-undo.
  define input parameter xyz as character no-undo.

  define variable qh as handle no-undo. 
  define variable bh as handle no-undo.
  define variable fh as handle no-undo.

  create buffer bh for table tbl.
  create query qh.
  qh:set-buffers( bh ).
  qh:query-prepare( "for each " + tbl ).
  qh:query-open.

  do transaction:
    qh:get-first( exclusive-lock ).
    fh = bh:buffer-field( fld ).
    display fh:buffer-value.
    fh:buffer-value = xyz.
  end.

  delete object bh.
  delete object qh.

  return.

end.

run x ( "customer", "name", "fred" ).

/* prove that we really did change it...
 */

find first customer no-lock.

display name.
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into it! :)

Comment: It's giving an error - could not create buffer object for table INS_TEST          (INS_TEST is my table name.)

Comment: The sample code updates fields in an existing record.  It does not create that record.

Comment: To create a record dynamically you want to use the BUFFER=CREATE() method on a buffer object.

Comment: Yes. I added BUFFER-CREATE() but I didn't create the table under PUB schema and was so getting the error. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the _field table for this. _file and _field (in fact, any table that starts with underscore) are your meta schema tables. They're your friends in learning dynamic programming or even understanding how your schema is currently defined, but I strongly recommend AGAINST trying to manipulate them yourself. And it doesn't really sound like you're trying to do that anyway, if I understand you correctly.
So once you have ins_test fields, you can do a static assign in a block (again, no need to query or cycle the underscore tables in this case):

```
CREATE ins_test.
ASSIGN ins_test.field1 = value1
       ins_test.field2 = value2
       ins_test.field3 = value3 NO-ERROR.
IF ERROR-STATUS:ERROR THEN DO:
   /* Treat your error here */
END.
```

Or, if you're really looking into dynamic assigning (which is going to be harder given you're probably still starting), you need to study dynamic queries and dynamic buffers so you understand those, then you could create the record by getting a handle to the buffer, then assign the table using the BUFFER-FIELD attribute to cycle the field names.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I want to create a generic insert procedure. Thanks for the response. :)

Comment: What do you want to have as input? A temp-table?

Comment: I want to give the table name as input.

Comment: Yes, but what about the data? How are you going to input that?